# Tensorflow Estimator - warm_start_from and model_dir

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

When using `tf.estimator` with `warm_start_from` **and** `model_dir`, and both `warm_start_from` directory and `model_dir` directory contain valid checkpoints, which checkpoint will be actually restored?

To give some context, my estimator code looks like

```
est = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    warm_start_from=warm_start_dir)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    est.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
    est.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
```

(Input functions use one shot iterators.)

So during the first iteration, when `model_dir` is empty, I want the warm start checkpoint to be loaded, but in the next epoch, i'd like to have the intermediate fine-tuned checkpoint from the last iteration in `model_dir` to be loaded. But at least from the logs, it looks like `warm_start_dir` is still being loaded.

I could probably override my estimator for the next iterations but I wonder if it shouldn't be built in the estimator some how.

Comment: Estimator will load the ops to warm start the weights, but will overwrite these with the value saved in the latest checkpoint. Estimator should add a feature to make sure there aren't any saved checkpoints before loading the warm_start weights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar issue, I've solved this by providing an initialization hook that is run when the session is started, and using `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` (though I can't take credit for this whole solution, as I saw something similar for another purpose elsewhere):

```
class InitHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    """initializes model from a checkpoint_path
    args:
        modelPath: full path to checkpoint
    """
    def __init__(self, checkpoint_dir):
        self.modelPath = checkpoint_dir
        self.initialized = False

    def begin(self):
        """
        Restore encoder parameters if a pre-trained encoder model is available and we haven't trained previously
        """
        if not self.initialized:
            log = logging.getLogger('tensorflow')
            checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(self.modelPath)
            if checkpoint is None:
                log.info('No pre-trained model is available, training from scratch.')
            else:
                log.info('Pre-trained model {0} found in {1} - warmstarting.'.format(checkpoint, self.modelPath))
                tf.train.warm_start(checkpoint)
            self.initialized = True
```

Then, for training:

```
initHook = InitHook(checkpoint_dir = warm_start_dir)
trainSpec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn = train_input_fn,
    max_steps = N_STEPS, 
    hooks = [initHook]
)
evalSpec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
    input_fn = eval_input_fn,
    steps = None,
    name = 'eval',
    throttle_secs = 3600
)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, trainSpec, evalSpec)
```

This runs once at the beginning to initialize variables from `warm_start_dir`. Later, when there are new checkpoints in the estimator `model_dir`, it continues warm_starting from there.

Comment: It’s great, thank you very much, solved my problem.

Comment: Is `initHook` been used only in the chief?